# Why arrow direction is changed on hover of menu links?

Tags: interaction-design, menu, dropdown, hyperlinks

Even after designing **hundreds** of sites I can't understand why it is good to change the direction of arrow in menu dropdowns.

Here I'm talking about hover event.

[image]

Comment: By the way i've never changed the arrow direction (on hover) in any projects I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break it down as two events:

1. HOVER -IN
2. HOVER -OUT

Both events has same purpose to show the direction of the UI element.

It is just an **indicator** of the direction the UI element will go, that could also reference a real-world handler. The sub-menu is hidden over the parent and so the arrow points down. When it is opened the arrow shows the menu will go up again

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why this would be useful in a hover event but...

The direction of the arrow is used to indicate what will happen when an event is triggered - in this case, triggering the event causes the menu to open downwards and, once the menu is open, this can then be re-triggered to collapse the menu upwards.

However, there is another issue: prior to interaction, how does the user know if these indicate the current state or the outcome of the trigger? Binary indicators (up/down, on/off, etc) are fraught with cognitive issues around their interpretation - just looking at one, you can't always tell if it's showing that action that *will* be preformed or the *current state* of the object or element it relates to. If you see a single button marked "on" does it mean that clicking the button will turn something on or that something is already on and clicking it will turn it off?

Comment: you are much right, Andrew . And I think most users don't even notice the change of arrow cause they were desperately searching for right link

Answer (score 0):

It is just an indicator of the **direction the UI element will go**. When it points down the user can expect that clicking/hovering will show something that will come down, and when up it will bring that same element up.

Another idea is it could also **reference a real-world handler**. It indicates the direction the UI element would go. Imagine yourself dragging this up or down.

[image: menu]

For simplicity and considering the Parent is in a context with other parents it stays in its original place instead of going down with its sub-menu.

Animating the opening/closing with [microinteractions](https://uxplanet.org/microinteractions-the-secret-to-great-app-design-4cfe70fbaccf#.wk9epnzer) helps the user-expectation and understanding of its functionality.

Comment: I request you to read question again. please

Comment: Of course :) As some sub-menus "open" when you hover the Parent and at the same time the arrow changes direction I thought that was the case. Now I guess you mean in cases where the sub-menu doesn't open but the arrow changes direction?

Comment: sorry, may be my mistake, i couldn't explain well. the issue here is NOT down arrow. After hover, why shopify changed the direction of that down-arrow to upward. For clarity, Go to http://shopify.com/

Comment: I checked the web. I still think the answer is "It is just an indicator of the direction the UI element will go, that could also reference a real-world handler". The sub-menu is hidden over the parent and so the arrow points down. When it is opened the arrow shows the menu will go up again.